# Extracting a single grid from a mdb file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, esri-geodatabase, xy

I'm trying to open ISRIC-WISE derived soil properties (available as MDB file from http://www.isric.org/data/) as a layer in ArcMap without much success. I know MDB are MS Access files that can be read in ArcMap as a geodatabase, but I'm not familiar with MDB files in GIS. I got to open the MDB file and see each one of the 20 derived soil properties as a spreadsheet, but not as a layer.

1) How can I see each of the 20 derived soil properties as a layer in ArcMap 10?

2) Once imported the 20 layers, how can I extract values of some X & Y points from each one of the 20 layers at the same time?

Comment: Could you add the headers and a couple of lines from one of the tables so we can see what you're dealing with?

Comment: Here it is. What can be seen below is the first two lines of the table.

OBJECTID;SNUM;AREA1;BULK_1t;BULK_1s;AREA2;BULK_2t;BULK_2s;AREA3;BULK_3t;BULK_3s;AREA4;BULK_4t;BULK_4s;AREA5;BULK_5t;BULK_5s;AREA6;BULK_6t;BULK_6s;AREA7;BULK_7t;BULK_7s;AREA8;BULK_8t;BULK_8s;AREA9;BULK_9t;BULK_9s;AREA10;BULK_10t;BULK_10s

Comment: 1;17833;47,0999985;1,350000000000000;-95,000000000000000;16,7000008;1,400000000000000;1,400000000000000;13,8999996;1,340000000000000;1,510000000000000;7,1999998;1,300000000000000;1,470000000000000;5,5999999;1,320000000000000;1,460000000000000;5,0000000;1,350000000000000;1,410000000000000;2,8000000;1,320000000000000;1,560000000000000;1,7000000;1,650000000000000;1,750000000000000;0,0000000;;;0,0000000;;